# Go to Declaration of node_modules code in WebStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

Any chance I could know from which node_module I can find the source code of the method query(arg).
Instead of showing node_modules could it show the name of the node_modules package (postgres, mongodb, express) etc.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I can't offer any workarounds for this issue, except from removing node_modules from javascript libraries (but they will be re-added on next project opening):( Please vote for [WEB-12107](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-12107) to be notified on any progress